Is it rightUri or rightsUri?
we found out that there are currently tokens in circulation with "rightUri" (like in the TZIP-21) and "rightsUri". See:
Versum (rightUri): https://bafybeiaotlgby2nwmuchjlsrbt5uv6pzscyzfiylrrlf7e5cjvcnzkxffy.ipfs.dweb.link/ Teia (rightUri): https://cache.teia.rocks/ipfs/QmR14AF7TNjWKSQ2643hZcn5LSL4L9zrXuCJp17jmztQkM
Pytezos (rightsUri): https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/blob/2f3ab66c385f77bec42bbe9f67d0a7ac3ee2fc69/src/pytezos/contract/token_metadata.py#L93 Objkt.com: rightsUri
Is this a typo or what is correct now?

According to the tzip-21 spec, the correct answer is the non-plural rightUri: https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-21/
The inconsistencies are likely due to the preceding property being plural: rights
You should contact the teams that have it wrong and see what can be done. If any high profile projects have used the wrong one, then its possible both will have to be supported. This has happened before with teams using snake case instead of camel case (e.g. artifact_uri instead of artifactUri). Some apps now support both to avoid degraded user experience

Update:
The author of the spec confirmed its a typo and it should have been the plural rightsUri. This has been updated, however the non-plural rightUri would need to be considered for backwards compatibility as many instances of this will likely remain
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/issues/4647

according to the author of the spec, it seems like it's the spec which has a typo, and should be amended.
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/issues/4647
